# What does this computed CSS mean?

Tags: css, reactjs, tailwind-css, google-chrome-devtools

I have a component that can either be *open* or *closed*. Depending on this state an attribute is added to the component accordingly (e.g. `data-state=open`).

The component applies some inline CSS using Tailwind to rotate child SVG components when `data-state=open`:

```
<Component className="[&[data-state=open]>svg]:rotate-180">
    <svg />
</Component>
```

This works, however the computed CSS as seen by the Chrome dev tools is quite strange:

[image: computed css]

What's going on here? This appears to be the equivalent of:

```
[data-state=open]>svg:rotate-180[data-state=open]>svg {
    ...
}
```

But what does this mean? Is it valid CSS or is this some dev tools display trick?

Answer (score 0):

Is it valid CSS and not some dev tools display trick – that is the expected rule output by Tailwind.

Tailwind uses the ampersand character, `&`, in [arbitrary variants](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/adding-custom-styles#arbitrary-variants) to mean "this" element.

The backslashes escape characters that would otherwise have special meaning in CSS.

So, the steps to build the rule selector (may not be same order as in Tailwind, but should demonstrate how the selector is constructed:

1. The raw class name:

   ```
   .[&[data-state=open]>svg]:rotate-180 {
   ```
2. Escape special characters:

   ```
   .\[\&\[data-state\=open\]>svg\]\:rotate-180 {
   ```
3. Substitute `&[data-state=open]>svg` into the selector, where `&` is itself:

   ```
    ( ------------------ & ----------------- )[data-state=open]>svg
                         ↓
   .\[\&\[data-state\=open\]>svg\]\:rotate-180[data-state=open]>svg {
   ```

Comment: But what does that CSS _mean_? If I were to explicitly write this same CSS into my stylesheets it seems like non-sense to me. Also, as written, this CSS string generates a very high order of _specificity_. So overriding it on a per-component basis is difficult.

Comment: The selector selects an `svg` whereby its direct parent has the `data-state` attribute with the value of `true` and has the `class` attribute whereby its value, separated by whitespace, contains one value of `[&[data-state=open]>svg]:rotate-180`. rotate-180 in Tailwind CSS with default configuration means transform: rotate(180deg), which means rotate the element 180 degrees.